# How can I change the initial value of `id` field?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have a `User` model, which generated the bellow table:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

in it the id is increase from `1`.

I have used my system in a spell, now I want to change the `id` of some user instance and start at `10000`.

in the database I can not change, it will report error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`qy`.`usermanage_user_groups`, CONSTRAINT `usermana_user_id_53f44f10_fk_qy_adm` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `usermanage_user` (`id`))
```

Is it possible to change the `id`? if there is some related factors, how can I solved it one by one, such as `usermanage_user_groups`?

Comment: Why would you want to change an `id` that refers to another table (or vice versa)?

Comment: id columns with PRIMARY KEY and AUTO_INCREMENT option should NOT be changed ny updating.. i repeat  should NOT be changed by updating

Comment: because I want the id start with `10000`.

Comment: Just update once.

Comment: @qg_java_17137 Why do you want `id` to start with `10000`? If you want to show this on UI front, just add 10000 to whatever id you get and show it. Changing values in DB isn't a good idea.

Comment: @vivek_23 thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The [`id`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) field is an automatic primary key field added by Django since you did not provide the `primary_key=True` property.

**NOTE**

Now, as the comments says you probably **should not have to change the behavior of that field** since it guarantee uniqueness throughout your data. See linked documentation for more information.

Considering you understood that by now, there is two possiblities for you in my opnion.

*Preferred solution I think*

1) Add a custom [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) and start it at `10000` and it will then update accordingly.

*Hack version*

2) Add a user with an `id` of 9999 in your database. This will result in auto-incrementing your `id` field according to this new value. It won't fill the values in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup sequence start from 10000 in your database. Also may trying manually add user with id 9999 through db manager.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of understand what you want to achieve, but I'm not sure if you want to retain the existing user data across your tables including user, usermanage_user, usermanage_user_groups;

Meaning, 
**Do you simply want to replace user_id from [1, 2, 3, 4, ......25] to [10000, 10001, 10002, 10004, ...... 10025] for the existing users?**

1] If yes, then manipulating tables in DB to safely update ID in all the referred table is one way. I can give a better solution here, if you share your schema structures / django models.

2] If no, you can simply set AUTO_INCREMENT to 10000, so that the following newly added users begin with 10000+

```
 `ALTER TABLE User AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;`
```